# Problema con un ejercicio de C

Tags: c, array

Hola buenas resulta que tengo un problema con un ejercicio, el enunciado es el siguiente:

-Escribir un programa que lea un archivo creado llamado "personas.txt".

Este archivo contiene datos de tres personas:(personas.txt)
·Nombre
·Apellido
·NIF
·Edad
·Altura

Ha de mostrar todos los datos de las personas por pantalla, si esas personas tienen 18 años o más:

Aquí el texto del fichero: (personas.txt)

```
 
Juan
Antonio
123456789
18
1.98

Manolo
Escobar
987654321
76
1.59

Cristiano
Ronaldo
542312345
31
1.86
```

Aquí os paso el código de mi programa que me falla:

```
int llegirMajorsEdat()
{
    int i;
    int edat;
    float altura;
    int NIF;
    char *nom;
    char *cognom;
    char linea[1024];
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen("persones.txt", "r");

    for(i=0; i<3; i++ )
    {
        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        nom = strtok(linea, " ");

        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        cognom = strtok(linea, " ");

        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        NIF = atoi(strtok(linea, " "));

        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        edat = atoi(strtok(linea, " "));
        printf("%d\n", edat );

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        altura = atof(fgets(linea, 11, file));

        if (edat >= 18) 
        {
            printf("--------------------------\n");
            printf("Aquesta persona és major d'edat\n");

            printf("%s", nom);
            printf("%s", cognom);
            printf("%d\n", NIF );
            printf("%d\n", edat );
            printf("%.2f\n", altura );
            printf("--------------------------\n");
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    char linea[1024];
    char persones[25];
    int i;
    int j;

    FILE * file;
    char * token;
    file = fopen("persones.txt", "r");

    llegirMajorsEdat();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, @GokuGod97 ! SOes tiene un editor de código integrado, porfavor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código de forma que todos puedan reproducir tu problema e intentar ayudarte con una solución!

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero es que mi código no se ve correctamente utilizando "<pre><code>"

Comment: Para indentar el código correctamente presiona 4 veces la tecla de espacio que quieres indentar, edita y pruebalo

Comment: vale, muchas gracias ahora funciona :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí voy, la razon por la cual no puedes obtener el resultado que buscas es porque al usar `fgets(<>,<>,<>);` estas obteniendo toda la linea y tienes resultados por lineas, lo mas recomendable en este caso es usar un archivo delimitado, ya que el espacio (" ") no es un buen amigo cuando se trata de tokenizar un string.

Este es el archivo "Personas.txt" que utilicé:

```
Juan,Antonio,123456789,18,1.98
Manolo,Escobar,987654321,76,1.59
Cristiano,Ronaldo,542312345,31,1.86
Miguel,Gomez,123432123,15,1.77
```

La idea es obtener al mayor de edad, no? entonces te muestro lo que hice para lograrlo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int llegirMajorsEdat(FILE *file)
{
    int i;
    int edat;
    float altura;
    char *NIF;
    char *nom;
    char *cognom;
    char linea[1024];

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fgets(linea, 1024, file);
        /* Imprime la linea actual.*/ puts(linea);
        nom = strtok(linea, ",");
        cognom = strtok(NULL, ",");
        NIF = strtok(NULL, ",");
        edat = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
        altura = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));

        if (edat >= 18) 
        {
            printf("--------------------------\n");
            printf("Aquesta persona és major d'edat\n");

            printf("%s ", nom);
            printf("%s\n", cognom);
            printf("%s \n", NIF );
            printf("%d\n", edat );
            printf("%.2f\n", altura );
            printf("--------------------------\n");
        }
    }
    return 1; // Sin esto no compilaba (strict)
}

int main()
{
    char linea[1024];
    char persones[25];
    int i;
    int j;

    FILE * file;
    char * token;
    file = fopen("archis.txt", "r");

    llegirMajorsEdat(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Es simple, primero se toma la primera linea a delimitar, luego llamamos a `strtok` por primera vez en la variable `nom`, luego delimitamos la linea actual por cada campo hasta llegar al último (\n) y luego pasar al siguiente ciclo del bucle for.

Por último, se verifica que sea mayor de edad y se imprimen los detalles.

> Has visto, que he agregado a `int llegirMajorsEdat()` un parametro llamado `FILE *file`, esto es para que no tengas que abrir el mismo archivo 2 veces al llamarlo desde la función `main()`, sino que lo pasas por parametro y listo!

---

Si te interesa el resultado que me dá al probarlo:

```
--------------------------
Aquesta persona Ts major d'edat
Juan Antonio
123456789
18
1.98
--------------------------
--------------------------
Aquesta persona Ts major d'edat
Manolo Escobar
987654321
76
1.59
--------------------------
--------------------------
Aquesta persona Ts major d'edat
Cristiano Ronaldo
542312345
31
1.86
--------------------------
```

Espero que te haya ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, de verdad. Eres un crack !!! Me ha servido de mucho :)